# how can i resolve TypeError: Cannot read property 'proteinname' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am developing the module where I have to save the searched item in the session and then I can use that item's value in my other request but in doing so I am getting "TypeError: Cannot set property 'proteinname' of undefined" when I try to access the req.expsession.proteinname in another route

app.js code:

```
const expsession = require('express-session')

app.use(expsession({secret: 'my secret', resave: false, saveUninitialized:false}));
```

protein.js code

```
router.post('/getsearchvalue',(req,res,next)=>{
    req.expsession = { proteinname: req.body.proteinname };
    res.render('searchresult')
})

router.get('/getsearchvalue',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.expsession.proteinname)
    var searchedproteinname = req.expsession.proteinname; })
```

when I try to access the above get request I am getting the error

Comment: The error is telling you that `req.expsession` does not exist. That's because it's always `req.session`, no matter what you call the `const` you use to set it up.

Comment: i had made the changes but still getting the same error

Comment: Can you update the question so it reflects what you current have?

Comment: i did change in the protein.js code as you suggested  `router.post('/getsearchvalue',(req,res,next)=>{
    req.session = { proteinname: req.body.proteinname };
    console.log("inside post")
    console.log(req.body.proteinname)
    res.render('searchresult')
    console.log(req.session.proteinname)
})` but i am still getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'proteinname' of undefined

Comment: Hmm, is it possible the error is about `req.body`? Your question title says `cannot read`, the question text says `cannot set`